# RSA Decryption fails in Windows 2012 & Windows 10

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, windows-server-2012

RSA decryption is failing in Windows Server 2012 & Windows 10, but works like a charm in Windows 7. Have placed below the code that also contains the relevant keys used.

```
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);

const string privatekey = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>m38MvfdL8epfiYvgw6ylMB7zPAKSStQLklCQEOworQwJxw39bXdnm4717BUm5700vZCbG9GBgjwHUxmrFrFsSJxMIdYhokT/DuYOC9Nsf2fiX5Uq+WtBfbSneEr6yVk2VB1fgba6XxoK9O3CKzieR1XxPEofxGRjrXzMe8nIMNc=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>33li38h5n1siKeu3LvsLF+JiytDAVLdRO6BkZ7btGcElTs/iir8ZIJFs2VvB5ELovk0iSBKZTNN/In4asEehaw==</P><Q>siDRbd2xQOyZnIOhfkjAt4QUNhskKRV56OkTvEawxloXZOssh0BjzuW8UVbiM3OuqgXUZm64eJyVghJacWXNRQ==</Q><DP>aafRWG5HGlGTCHDabcrhRsyQ2sTxedwl+uPtNJ/m35tS0T02JVUOQzieVvGr7Qi5U2fSgnLQqeMAo8UtRxTGuw==</DP><DQ>LB724Pi9k/BG6D6ufKI2of4kJ3a3kTmRlcBNtB/qX2cnTkb2I5YuYqwC5j7YDpiD1fdVsf2Q0ccvPSWgo1/s5Q==</DQ><InverseQ>YnPBkCyRyRnVWJPaJg507VdJpEPPeacdJ0wUJfiJgOfJPo01JLOWtgPWVqpW+pDTouv77qn7N1sIRo+IiyzsRA==</InverseQ><D>KEOLvxzr82Zm+qzXtJNd6sn43c8kpm+l12s5AsjD95soZPzAZLoIgAVStKD9hABASd3J7DghuuFkXCZHYQbsLLEeRY2TuuS/e6yyYV0+KNMRMrZAZ2DdWOdsfUmbQMiJNVTLmkwBgFLaFmcZ/DmPBMUYuJmFO9Tg6vEDCg45b5E=</D></RSAKeyValue>";
var dataByte = Convert.FromBase64String("YfFFh5cquMP8qMls+7e1WF23addkU9vLuK4W5U8R0zclbw1SJk+8QC8K17dgN5mXFKEifj669H7fAKfUphWDLqDSsodfFcGbElOC5J9ybf30Or1NPH9g2OTjIAaWluBjAYpg/qEtvJkvzwFpeqWoVOfNdwn51igCbPZKKi04tw==");

rsa.FromXmlString(privatekey);

        //var dataNotWorkingByte = Convert.FromBase64String("YfFFh5cquMP8qMls+7e1WF23addkU9vLuK4W5U8R0zclbw1SJk+8QC8K17dgN5mXFKEifj669H7fAKfUphWDLqDSsodfFcGbElOC5J9ybf30Or1NPH9g2OTjIAaWluBjAYpg/qEtvJkvzwFpeqWoVOfNdwn51igCbPZKKi04tw==");

        var dataWorkingByte = Convert.FromBase64String("I2S7t/BHFZo7JZFVUCHSSckHcWEASiZNjHmR5O1495y5RIej7d8PfnXjQYUrN1U352RAo373XSDuVhhFwS9XijI6lMJH/rlMjFIXOegcOrBJI406ZpF0dmbBc+Wq4rmBngT6fzrqvLLhijfRUq1m+K2dEfOkOuzRCsXKRKCOZBA=");

var descryptedString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptedByte);
```

The following exception is thrown

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: **Bad Data**.

**EDIT**
Exception happens only when attempting to decrypt text with double padding (==). Have provided samples of working and not working texts

```
        var dataNotWorkingByte = Convert.FromBase64String("YfFFh5cquMP8qMls+7e1WF23addkU9vLuK4W5U8R0zclbw1SJk+8QC8K17dgN5mXFKEifj669H7fAKfUphWDLqDSsodfFcGbElOC5J9ybf30Or1NPH9g2OTjIAaWluBjAYpg/qEtvJkvzwFpeqWoVOfNdwn51igCbPZKKi04tw==");

        var dataWorkingByte = Convert.FromBase64String("I2S7t/BHFZo7JZFVUCHSSckHcWEASiZNjHmR5O1495y5RIej7d8PfnXjQYUrN1U352RAo373XSDuVhhFwS9XijI6lMJH/rlMjFIXOegcOrBJI406ZpF0dmbBc+Wq4rmBngT6fzrqvLLhijfRUq1m+K2dEfOkOuzRCsXKRKCOZBA=");
```

And the length of the data is well small and does not exceed 50 characters.

Thanks in advance for your time!!

Comment: please check your dataByte is encrypted with the RSA Algorithm

Comment: If I make the line above `Decrypt` read `dataByte = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello"), false);` it works fine so either 1024 is an incorrect key size or the input base64 data is not correct.

Comment: Works for me using Mono.

Comment: @AlexK., sorry, failed to add the decryption is not failing in all the cases, this seems to be failing only when we have double padding (==) at the end of the encrypted string. Will Edit the post to reflect this.

Comment: Somewhere the leading zero byte that should have been present is getting stripped. `Enumerable.Concat(new byte[] { 0 }, Convert.FromBase64String("YfFFh5cquMP8qMls+7e1WF23addkU9vLuK4W5U8R0zclbw1SJk+8QC8K17dgN5mXFKEifj669H7fAKfUphWDLqDSsodfFcGbElOC5J9ybf30Or1NPH9g2OTjIAaWluBjAYpg/qEtvJkvzwFpeqWoVOfNdwn51igCbPZKKi04tw==")).ToArray()` is successfully decrypted. You'll need to plug in some code that detects arrays that aren't exactly 128 bytes in length and pads them as necessary.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, you are right, this indeed works. The issue could be with the 3rd party Javascript Library we are using to encryption. Have done it as you had suggested and everything seems to working fine now, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Exception happens only when attempting to decrypt text with double padding (==). Have provided samples of working and not working texts

The Base64 padding changes the length of the `byte[]`, but RSA decryption requires a `byte[]` whose bit-length is the same as the key length.

The Base64 value

```
I2S7t/BHFZo7JZFVUCHSSckHcWEASiZNjHmR5O1495y5RIej7d8PfnXjQYUrN1U
352RAo373XSDuVhhFwS9XijI6lMJH/rlMjFIXOegcOrBJI406ZpF0dmbBc+Wq4r
mBngT6fzrqvLLhijfRUq1m+K2dEfOkOuzRCsXKRKCOZBA=
```

is equal to the hexadecimal value

```
2364BBB7F047159A3B2591555021D249C9077161004A264D8C7991E4ED78F79C
B94487A3EDDF0F7E75E341852B375537E76440A37EF75D20EE561845C12F578A
323A94C247FEB94C8C521739E81C3AB049238D3A6691747666C173E5AAE2B981
9E04FA7F3AEABCB2E18A37D152AD66F8AD9D11F3A43AECD10AC5CA44A08E6410
```

Which is 128 bytes, or 1024-bit, so it isn't an outright wrong value for RSA decryption.

On the other hand, the Base64 value

```
YfFFh5cquMP8qMls+7e1WF23addkU9vLuK4W5U8R0zclbw1SJk+8QC8K17dgN5m
XFKEifj669H7fAKfUphWDLqDSsodfFcGbElOC5J9ybf30Or1NPH9g2OTjIAaWlu
BjAYpg/qEtvJkvzwFpeqWoVOfNdwn51igCbPZKKi04tw==
```

is equal to the hexadecimal value

```
61F14587972AB8C3FCA8C96CFBB7B5585DB769D76453DBCBB8AE16E54F11D337
256F0D52264FBC402F0AD7B76037999714A1227E3EBAF47EDF00A7D4A615832E
A0D2B2875F15C19B125382E49F726DFDF43ABD4D3C7F60D8E4E320069696E063
018A60FEA12DBC992FCF01697AA5A854E7CD7709F9D628026CF64A2A2D38B7
```

Which is only 127 bytes.  Therefore it is not a valid blob to decrypt under a 1024-bit key.

The real error lies in whatever is producing that value.  RSA encryption always produces an answer of the key size:

[RFC 3447, section 7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-7) shows both OAEP and PKCS1-v1_5 as ending in `I2OSP (c, k)`, where "k denotes the length in octets of the modulus n".

[I2OSP(x, xLen)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-4.1) has the cautionary note: "note that one or more leading digits will be zero if x is less than 256^(xLen-1)".  My only speculation (aside from corrupted data) is that you somewhere encountered a system that removed the leading zeros as being irrelevant.

Comment: Many thanks for the great explanation, this pretty much clears the air for me to take corrective action. Although, I am still puzzled about how the decryption is working fine for 127 bytes encrypted text in case of my Windows 7 machines.

Comment: @Vasan My only guess is that Windows 7 had a bug where it was processing one-byte-short data as starting with 0x00, and that bug may have accidentally been fixed during some other change in the 8+ code.